# Is the aluminium foil usable in this condition?

Tags: aluminum-foil

As the title says, is the aluminium foil still usable in this condition?

If you notice, there's a very obvious white portion in the center of the aluminum foil and the entire roll is like that. Usually when I buy it from the store, it is pure silver without the white line. However when I keep it for some time, this white line appears which appears to me that the foil could be "spoilt"?

[image: Aluminium foil with white stripe]

May I also ask what is the name of the condition of this aluminum foil and what causes it to be like this.

Comment: What potential problem do you see?   It just looks like it have been formed to a pan.

Comment: @paparazzo it's the whitish line in the middle.

Comment: the horizontal non-shiny stripe looks like it may be oxidation (aluminum oxide), which is the aluminum equivalent of rust.  I have no idea if it's an issue for food safety.

Comment: @Joe Now you do (see answer)  **;-)**

Comment: Odd looking stripe. Are you keeping The Al near a volatile acid or base?

Comment: @WayfaringStranger no i did not. i just kept it like how i bought it from the supermarket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's just [aluminium oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide) (Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>) and it's harmless as:

- it's insoluble in water
- it's nearly insoluble in alcohol.
- is very hard (Basically the same material as a [ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby) or a [sapphire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapphire))
- it's chemically nearly inert
- Is basically the same substance as the non-shiny side of the Aluminium foil

So it's definitely useable for all intents and purposes. (including cooking **;-)** )

Comment: It's also just a thicker layer of what all aluminium foil has on the surface.

Comment: not doubting you, however i can't help but to ask if there's any studies or sources to prove this? My parents are health freak but i have so much of such foils at home. If i can't convince them, they are all going to waste.

Comment: @Astralis if you want scientific **proof:** send the foil off  to a chemical lab and have it tested and provide the test results to your parents.  From where I am across the Internet, that's what it *looks like* with a high certitude, but without a sample, I cannot test this in my lab... **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**